# Google Script if statement does not check user vs entered data

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a booking program in Google Sheets where a user can pick their name (uses data verification to provide a list of emails) and then the cell is then placed under protection so no other user can change the booking.

The strange thing that happens is that a person can enter in another person's email and then the cell is protected by the entered email not the user. The user can enter in a non-email string and it does not protect the cell.

**The desired result would be that if the user's email and the data entered is the same, protect the cells otherwise it is free to be edited.**

Any help would be appreciated!

```
function onEdit(e){
  var CurrentUser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
  var range_DataEntered = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var DataEntered = range_DataEntered.getValue();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var Cell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if (CurrentUser = DataEntered) {
      var protection = range_DataEntered.protect()

      // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
      // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.

      protection.addEditor(CurrentUser);
     if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
    }
  else {
  //remove protection, set everyone to edit
    range_DataEntered.protect().setDomainEdit(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (CurrentUser = DataEntered)` needs to be 
`if(CurrentUser === DataEntered)`

A single `=` will assign a value not check for equivalency.

Comment: Wow. Many thanks. I tried == and it didn't work then = but was completely unaware === existed. Time to dig into JavaScript a but more.